# SQL Server CLR stored procedures in AWS

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, amazon-web-services, sqlclr

I have 2 **SQL Server CLR stored procedure**s and we are moving database server to **AWS**. 
I would like to know if those CLR stored procedures will work after move to AWS? 

Can use SQL Server CLR stored procedures in AWS? do I need to do anything special? or maybe I need to rewrite them to T-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After additional research I found that it is possible to have **SQL Server CLR stored procedures** in **AWS**

In the David Iffland article [How To Use SQL CLR in Amazon AWS RDS](http://notebookheavy.com/2012/05/23/how-to-use-sql-clr-in-amazon-aws-rds/) there is step by step instruction how to do it.

There is an improvement on the new version of AWS DB Parameter Group and it just require changing changing the flag **clr enabled** to **1**.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer the case with SQL Server 2017 in AWS, been discussing this at Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8zbqvw/sql_server_2017_clr_support/?st=JLOF9U8V&sh=8a8d06b6) with other users and have submitted a ticket for AWS to provide more info.