# Deploying my first SQLCLR stored procedure to Amazon RDS SQL Server instance

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, amazon-rds, sqlclr

At my current consulting assignments they are letting me use CLR Sprocs which is great (some past engagements did not for bogus reasons).

I followed all the steps at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx

but made a simple Sproc in Visual Studio:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void TestCLR_001 ()
    {
       Debug.Write("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and my admin ran:

```sql
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

But when I build solution or deploy solution no errors but they never make it to SQL Server. I.e.

```sql
use pls;

 Exec TestCLR_001;
```

does not work.

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 3
>   Could not find stored procedure 'TestCLR_001'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as configuring the RDS instance goes, have you tried setting `clr enabled` to `1` in the AWS DB Parameter Group? (approach taken from the following answer: [SQL Server CLR stored procedures in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777261/sql-server-clr-stored-procedures-in-aws/26778518#26778518) ).

Also, your method attribute might be wrong. I saw another issue just like this recently, and we got it fixed, but no definite confirmation on which combination of changes ultimately did the trick. But, I think the `[SqlProcedure]` is missing parenthesis and should be `[SqlProcedure()]`.

First try recompiling after adding in the parenthesis to the `SqlProcedure` attribute. If that doesn't work, try setting `clr enabled` to `1` in the AWS DB Parameter Group.

Also, a better / easier test would be to just have it do a `PRINT` statement by changing `Debug.Write` to be `SqlContext.Pipe.Send`.