# SQLCLR Support on AWS SQL Server 2017 RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, sqlclr

I need to load an Assembly in AWS SQL Server 2017 RDS.

I am not able to find it in the documentation. Is this possible? If yes, then how?

This is similar to, but not a duplicate of, "[SQL Server CLR stored procedures in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778518/577765)", since I need to create the assembly in SQL Server 2017 AWS and changing parameter `clr enabled` to 1 is not possible in this version, and this is not addressed in that question or answer.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for accepting :). Not sure what the plan is, but I think you should probably award the bounty to @BeardOfTriumph because when you started the bounty, their answer did accurately describe the situation, while mine still said that module signing would likely work if AWS merely re-enabled the `CLR enabled` config setting.

Comment: @Solomon Rutzky I must appreciate your dedication on SO. I accepted your answer because I think you spent much time answering this question and also edited with detailed explanation. Bounty is awarded to BeardOfTriumph for short and simple asnwer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this used to work (I did test on AWS 2016 SP1 CU2), it seems that it is now (as of SQL Server 2017) being blocked by AWS due to the new "CLR strict security" instance-level configuration setting.

As per the [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8zbqvw/sql_server_2017_clr_support/e5ghoew/) noted in the [comment on the answer linked by @Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778518/577765),

> In RDS SQL Server 2016 and backwards, CLR is supported in SAFE mode and using assembly bits only. Since in SQL Server 2017 the parameter 'CLR strict security' is set to 1 by default and even using CLR SAFE and assembly bits options, you will receive an error because the parameter 'CLR strict security' need to be disabled or need to trust the assembly by using the stored procedure "sp_add_trusted_assembly". But this stored procedure, requires sysadmin permissions, that is not supported in RDS SQL Server as you can see in the Microsoft Documentation: ...
>
> Therefore, RDS does not support UNSAFE assemblies, and all the assemblies are treated like UNSAFE with this new feature, the feature CLR will not be supported in RDS SQL Server 2017. The parameter 'CLR strict security' will be blocked by our automation's and customers will not be able to modify this. CLR uses CAS (code access security) in the .NET Framework and is no longer supported as a security issue. A CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = SAFE may be able to access to external resources, unmanaged code and acquire sysadmin privileges.
> ...
> It is unfortunate that because of the above, CLR feature is NOT SUPPORTED in RDS SQL Server 2017.
>
> You can however, also consider using SQL Server on EC2 which gives you full Administrative privileges just like you would with on-prem installations.

At first I was hopeful that there would be a way to get AWS to lift this restriction, given that AWS's reasons are:

1. > the parameter 'CLR strict security' need to be disabled or need to trust the assembly by using the stored procedure "sp_add_trusted_assembly"

   This is not entirely true. You can also use [Module Signing](https://modulesigning.info/) (which is the better approach anyway)
2. > RDS does not support UNSAFE assemblies, and all the assemblies are treated like UNSAFE with this new feature

   That wording is a MAJOR failing on Microsoft's part. Assemblies are *not* treated as `UNSAFE` in an operational sense, only in the *requirements for being loaded*. Meaning *ALL* assemblies, even those marked as `SAFE` and `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, must pass the same checks previously reserved for only `UNSAFE` assemblies.

Since both of those reasons are essentially misunderstandings, I thought that maybe AWS could re-allow "CLR enabled" and just support `SAFE` assemblies via Module Signing. But, then I re-read the message from "AWS Premium Support" and noticed that he ("Johnson") stated that the reason for not supporting `sp_add_trusted_assembly` was that it requires `sysadmin` permissions, which is not supported. The Module Signing approach requires granting the certificate-based login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission, and only a `sysadmin` can do that. So not even that will work . Looks like your only option there is to run an EC2 VM with SQL Server running on it (suggested by AWS support and [@BeardOfTriumph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222732/577765)).

This situation is very similar to Azure: Azure SQL Database does not support SQLCLR at all (though it previously did for about 18 months, ending abruptly in mid-April, 2016), but you can run SQL Server on an Azure VM for full SQLCLR support, and more recently they introduced Azure SQL Database Managed Instances, which supports SQLCLR.

Regardless, creating from a DLL was never supported, only creating from a `VARBINARY` literal / hex bytes. And you can convert a DLL into a `VARBINARY` string using an open source utility that I created, [BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/SqlQuantumLeap/BinaryFormatter/releases/latest). Also, please see my series on this:
[SQLCLR vs SQL Server 2017](https://sqlquantumleap.com/category/programming/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017/)

Comment: Surely, +1 for your efforts and explanation. Currently, I am reading https://sqlquantumleap.com/category/programming/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017/ (which is, by the way, a very good page) and will update.

Comment: @Tajinder Hi there. Thanks :). And I just checked again and it does seem like this might no longer be supported at all on AWS. I haven't play with AWS in over a year, but my notes indicate that there is no server-level access (sysadmin or otherwise). Meaning, no access to the `[master]` DB. Is this correct? If so, then there is nothing we can do, even if they once again allowed the "CLR Enabled" setting to be enabled. We would still need to create a Certificate, a Login from it, and grant that Login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission. Can't do that without access to `[master]`, unfortunately :(

Comment: Today is my second day of working on SQL Server and .Net Applications, So, it is possible I can ask a silly question or pass statement. My IT team has given me access to the SQL Server RDS. When I connect through my user there is a`[master]` db listed to which I am able to connect. However, I am still doing research on the internet regarding the same.

Comment: @Tajinder Well, if there is a `[master]` DB then _maybe_ there is some hope? If you want an easy test, just download my [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/) project as it has a simple, pure T-SQL installer, and all assemblies are signed. Just update the install script with a) your target DB name, and b) set the `@MaxAllowedAccessLevel` variable to `1` and see if it installs. We will have our answer either way.

Comment: I ma getting error when running SQL# `Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 2517
Line 326, Msg 50000: 
"CLR Integration" needs to be enabled, yet the current Login
does not have permission to perform this action. This change
can only be done by a Login that either has the "ALTER SETTINGS"
server-level permission, OR is a member of either the "sysadmin"
or the "serveradmin" fixed server roles.`

Comment: Now, I am following steps from https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/ getting the error when creating `login` (certificate is successfully created) when running `CREATE LOGIN [SQL2017-ClrStrictSecurity2-Login]
FROM CERTIFICATE [SQL2017-ClrStrictSecurity2-Cert];`  error: `Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the certificate 'SQL2017-ClrStrictSecurity2-Cert', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on the error I am getting? Anyways, thanks for your support.

Comment: @Tajinder You say that you created the certificate successfully. Did you create the certificate in the `master` DB, or did you create it in your user DB? It needs to be in `master`. However, even if you are able to do that, and create the Login from it, and then grant the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission, it still won't work if Amazon has prevented the enabling of the `clr enabled` configuration setting, and it sounds like they have. Which is quite unfortunate. According to the thread on Reddit, they won't allow anything requiring `sysadmin` permission, and granting `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` requires it.

Comment: I created a certificate in my user. Yes, you are right and also as answered by @BeardOfTriumph, Unfortunately, it seems that creating `assembly` on SQL Server 2017  RDS as of now is not possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Tajinder Right, unfortunately. I adjusted my answered based on re-reading the discussion on Reddit, which was confirmed by BeardOfTriumph.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky have any of these restrictions changed since your post? I'm confused in my situation. I have an RDS SQL 2017 instance that was upgraded in place from RDS SQL 2012 and the safe assembly and related functions still work on the upgraded 2017 instance. Because RDS makes upgrading editions harder than versions, I have a clean 2017 instance I'm trying to migrate to, but I'm running into these assembly problems that you describe here.

Comment: @dev_etter I don't use AWS so am not aware of the current options, but when I checked last year it was still not mentioned as an available option (and I don't think it will change). I'm actually quite (pleasantly) surprised to hear that it continues working when upgrading from 2012 to 2017. I wonder if that's by design or an oversight in the config. Maybe this is a work around (i.e. install Free version of [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_57167412) on a new 2012 DB of the desired edition, immediately upgrade to 2017/2019, then load everything else)? My free tier expired, can you please try?

Comment: Tangent: Convert the .dll to a hex-string (for the varbinary literal) using Powershell:  
`[System.BitConverter]::ToString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$pwd\YOURFILE.dll")).Replace("-", "") > hex.txt`

Comment: @Granger Cool. Always good to have options. One benefit of my [BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/SqlQuantumLeap/BinaryFormatter/releases/latest) is that it uses line continuation to wrap the otherwise very long line of the binary literal to multiple lines which are much easier to deal with. I suppose I can just publish a PowerShell version of that code. Hmmm...

Comment: "Assemblies are not treated as UNSAFE in an operational sense, only in the requirements for being loaded. Meaning ALL assemblies...must pass the same checks previously reserved for only UNSAFE assemblies." -- are you sure about this? I thought the whole situation here was with MS doing away with code-access security (trust levels), so now all SQLCLR code runs as though it's UNSAFE (full trust).  Previously you could lock down the code (e.g. `SAFE` would be restricted) but now that's impossible to enforce.  Hence even module signed CLR must have "unsafe assembly" permission.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-strict-security: "A CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = SAFE may be able to access external system resources, call unmanaged code, and acquire sysadmin privileges. ...clr strict security is enabled by default, and treats SAFE and EXTERNAL_ACCESS assemblies as if they were marked UNSAFE."  -- i.e. since even "SAFE" assemblies can no longer be restricted in what they do, now one can have SQL treat them as though UNSAFE [because there's no real boundary anymore]

Comment: In other words, I don't see how in the current state of the world, that we could get SQLCLR in a multitenant host anymore (like RDS), since there'd be no way for AWS to safely limit one tenant's SQLCLR from messing with other tenants on the same instance

Comment: NB: I read your post, where you show that right now, _empirically_ SQLCLR is still having [some/most/all?] things enforced, but my understanding is that CAS is deprecated, so there's no guarantee that will continue to be the case even if it happens to be now.

Comment: @MarkSowul The conclusion you came to based on the documentation is reasonable. However, I'm 99.x% certain that the doc is incorrect. I believe that assumptions were made based on changes in newer .NET Framework versions where CAS was no longer used. I'm not convinced that any testing was done to prove that the scenario could actually happen. I think it was simply assumed that it could and either nobody understood SQLCLR enough to know it couldn't or know how to prove it. I found a reference stating that SQLCLR enabled a switch to continue using CAS, so it should have been a non-issue.

Comment: @MarkSowul "_my understanding is that CAS is deprecated, so there's no guarantee that will continue to be the case even if it happens to be now._" True, if SQLCLR is ever upgraded to use newer CLR, _then_ there needs to be a discussion and a new approach. But, that certainly is not the case with SQL Server 2017 and 2019, nor Azure SQL Managed Instance, nor even Azure SQL DB (which had SQLCLR shut off 18 months after it was finally enabled). I believe this was a knee-jerk overreaction due to lack of understanding of their own product that helped nobody while screwing quite a few customers.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately in 2017+, it is not supported. And even if you did find some way to hack into the settings and get it to work, it would be in no way supported by Amazon when it decided to break. We went round and round trying to get it to work based on the fact that it would work in 2016, but they did completely disable it with the new security settings in SQL Server 2017. One of the several reasons we ended up sticking with an EC2 instance hosting SQL Server, as opposed to RDS.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this sad situation. +1

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to confirm that, based on a support chat from earlier today, **the CLR is still NOT supported for Sql2019 in RDS**.

1. Aws won't allow "CLR strict security" to be set to false, because "security reasons". (Which is a misinformed decision, as [proved here](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/10/30/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-9-does-permission_set-still-matter-or-is-everything-now-unsafe/) by [Solomon Rusky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577765). ...if it was, they'd disable CLR for pre-2017 versions too.)
2. [`sp_add_trusted_assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-add-trusted-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) cannot be used because the ["master" RDS user account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html) is not a member of "sysadmin" nor does it have "CONTROL SERVER" permission.
3. You can't grant a login the "UNSAFE ASSEMBLY" permission ([see the "Microsoft SQL Server security" section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html)), which is required for the [other, more complicated approach](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/) to get CREATE/ALTER ASSEMBLY to work.

Comment: ANY CLR is still NOT supported for Sql2019 in RDS: Safe, Unsafe, External?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't matter which you want.

Comment: ok, then I edit my question: ANY CLR already not absolutely supported by SQL 2019 RDS.

Comment: That's effectively the same question, so it has the same answer.

Comment: Thank you @Granger, it was statement only after your answer. ;-)